# phpMyAdmin replace text in a field with percent in text

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Using phpMyAdmin. Moved data from Windows server and trying to replace case in urls but not finding the matches. Need slashes as I don't want to replace text in anything but the urls (in post table). I think the %20 are the problem somwhow?

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = replace(field, '/user%20name/', '/User%20Name/')
```

Example:

```
https://www.example.com/forum/uploads/user%20name/GFCI%20Stds%20Rev%202006%20.pdf
```

Comment: phpmyadmin is a php application, not a database

Comment: `%20` is a space character

Comment: What both said ^

Also you could just do a dump.sql and run a preg_replace() or just plain normal str_replace()...